# How to make a reusable & tab focusable React modal using portal

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, accessibility, react-dom, react-portal

I have a modal created with react-dom portal and this is being used more than once to display different modals.

```
 <>
      <button onClick={OnClick}>
        {icon}
      </button>
      {isOpen &&
        createPortal(
          <div tabIndex={-1}>
              <button onClick={handleClose}>
                <CloseIcon />
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>{children}</div>
          </div>,
          document.body,
        )}
    </>
```

I'm passing different contents to the `children` (input, anchor, button) in different modals. 
 And (**1) once the modal is opened** > (**2) press tab key**, I want the **(3) first focusable-element** > **(4) to the last element** > **(5) close icon button**
focused in the modal. I've passed `tabIndex` to the portal div like the pasted code, but this didn't work. I guess it's because I'm using the modals in many places (max 3) and they exists in the DOM tree. **How can I make this generic modal tab-focusable?** 
 
Thank you.